# IF EXISTS (check if json object contains unique id), UPDATE table, ELSE INSERT into table

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I want to use IF EXISTS in my query to check whether an object contains a "seqId" or not. I'm trying to update or insert into a table from OPENJSON. This json object @identObj has an array of objects, some objects may have a "seqId," and some might not. The ones that have a "seqId" should update into the "case_ident_to_inv" table, if the "seqId" does not exist it should insert into that table, the "case_ident_to_inv" table. The output of inserting into the table is a unique seqId. I tried implementing an IF EXISTS statement and I thought the syntax was correct but I'm getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'IF'.

```
DECLARE @identObj NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
  {  
    "investigators": [
         {"importId": 177, "userId": 120, "invTypeCd": "LI", "seqId": 50}, 
         {"importId": 177, "userId": 124, "invTypeCd": "SI", "seqId": 50}, 
         {"importId": 177, "userId": 120, "invTypeCd": "RV", "seqId": 50}, 
         {"importId": 177, "userId": 123, "invTypeCd": "SI"},
     ]
   }
]';
```

Data for "case_ident_to_inv" table

```
+------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-------+
|  importId  | userId |  invTypeCd  |  caseIdentId  | seqId |
+------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-------+
| 177        | 120    | LI          | 10200         | 50    | 
| 177        | 124    | SI          | 10200         | 51    | 
| 177        | 120    | RV          | 10200         | 52    |
| 177        | 123    | SI          | 10200         |       |<--- seqId OUTPUT AFTER INSERT
+------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-------+
```

The caseIdentId and importId will always be the same, there can be identical userId's and invTypeCd's, seqId is always unique.

Stored Procedure

```
select I.*
INTO #tmpInvs
FROM OPENJSON(@identObj)
WITH (
    invs NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS caseIdentInvs
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (caseIdentInvs.invs)
WITH (
    userId INT,
    invTypeCd CHAR(5),
    importId INT,
    seqId INT
) I;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT i.*,ci.case_ident_id AS case_ident_id, ki.inv_type_name AS inv_type_name
    FROM #tmpInvs i
    INNER JOIN case_idents ci ON i.importId=ci.import_id
    INNER JOIN kdd_inv_type ki ON i.invTypeCd=ki.inv_type_cd
)

IF EXISTS (SELECT i.seqId FROM #tmpInvs i WHERE i.seqId != NULL)
UPDATE T
SET
    inv_id = ct.userId,
    inv_type_cd = ct.invTypeCd,
    inv_type_name = ct.inv_type_name
FROM case_ident_to_inv T
INNER JOIN cte AS ct ON ct.case_ident_id = T.case_ident_id

WHERE seq_id = ct.seqId

ELSE

INSERT INTO case_ident_to_inv(inv_id, case_ident_id, inv_type_cd, inv_type_name)
SELECT userId, case_ident_id, invTypeCd, inv_type_name
FROM cte
```

Comment: a _CTE_ expect `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE` nothing else. You can use `IF EXISTS` before the _CTE_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put IF after the cte declaration, because the next command is the one, which must use the cte. However you can replace the if / update / insert construct with a single merge statement. Something like this:

```
    merge case_ident_to_inv as Target
using (select * from cte) as Source 
on Target.case_ident_id = Source.case_ident_id
when matched then update set
    inv_id = Source.userId,
    inv_type_cd = Source.invTypeCd,
    inv_type_name = Source.inv_type_name
when not matched then
    insert(inv_id, case_ident_id, inv_type_cd, inv_type_name)
    values(Source.userId, Source.case_ident_id, Source.invTypeCd, Source.inv_type_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

A *CTE* need to `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE`. From [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns. A CTE can also be specified in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of the defining SELECT statement of the view.

You can move the `IF EXISTS` up as

```
   select I.*
    INTO #tmpInvs
    FROM OPENJSON(@identObj)
    WITH (
        invs NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
    ) AS caseIdentInvs
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (caseIdentInvs.invs)
    WITH (
        userId INT,
        invTypeCd CHAR(5),
        importId INT,
        seqId INT
    ) I;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT i.seqId FROM #tmpInvs i WHERE i.seqId != NULL)
    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT i.*,ci.case_ident_id AS case_ident_id, ki.inv_type_name AS inv_type_name
        FROM #tmpInvs i
        INNER JOIN case_idents ci ON i.importId=ci.import_id
        INNER JOIN kdd_inv_type ki ON i.invTypeCd=ki.inv_type_cd
    )
    UPDATE T
    SET
        inv_id = ct.userId,
        inv_type_cd = ct.invTypeCd,
        inv_type_name = ct.inv_type_name
    FROM case_ident_to_inv T
    INNER JOIN cte AS ct ON ct.case_ident_id = T.case_ident_id

    WHERE seq_id = ct.seqId

    ELSE

    INSERT INTO case_ident_to_inv(inv_id, case_ident_id, inv_type_cd, inv_type_name)
    SELECT userId, case_ident_id, invTypeCd, inv_type_name
    FROM cte
```

Comment: The if statement works, but I'm not getting the results I'm looking for. All objects are getting inserted into the table, instead of updating the ones that have a seqId already, do you know what I may be doing wrong or what I'm missing?